# python, selenium, phantomjs -> page not found

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm scraping this one site and it worked fine for like a month. Today I ran my script but it just downloaded the html of an error page (page not found). 
The script runs as a cgi on my webserver.

I checked the link in my desktop browser and everything went fine, e.g. the site opened as expected.

The url is: https://www.check24.de/handyvertrag/iphone-8/?activeForm=device&data_included=2000&minutes_included=flatrate&hwprop_model=198&young_tariff=no&orderby=empfehlung_preis&hwprop_color=egal&hwprop_memorysize=egal

My script for opening the site is the usual procedure:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = path_to_pjs)
driver.get(basis_url)
```

Does anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Also, have you tried accessing a completely different URL, e.g., http://www.example.com?

Comment: And what do you mean when you say “it just downloaded the HTML of an error page”? What does your script do and what was its output that led you to that conclusion?

Comment: Do you get different results if you run the script on your local machine, i.e., not on your server?

Comment: @Ian the script downloads the html of the visited site and saves it on the server. And the html that is download ist just the sellers "page not found" site, i.e. the url used in script is not found on the server when used by the script (?!) but is found when I use a desktop browser. As soon as I can I will run the script on a local machine. I tried several other urls of the seller, like his main page. They work fine, only the sites with the offers give me a faulty result.

Comment: @Ian the problem seems to be the headless browser. I tested with my desktop machine and while using geckodriver, everything went fine, when i used phantomjs he couldnt find the page as described above. Unfortunately I cannot use chromedriver or geckodriver on my webserver.

Comment: Have you tried a different headless browser? PhantomJS is no longer under active development, and both Firefox and Chrome support reliable headless operation.